# In Haskell, how do you restrict functions to only one constructor of a data type?

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

I'm not sure how to word this question. Say I'm trying to pass the paths of tmpfiles around, and I want to capture the idea that there are different formats of tmpfile, and each function only works on one of them. This works:

```
data FileFormat
  = Spreadsheet
  | Picture
  | Video
  deriving Show

data TmpFile = TmpFile FileFormat FilePath
  deriving Show

videoPath :: TmpFile -> FilePath
videoPath (TmpFile Video p) = p
videoPath _ = error "only works on videos!"
```

But there must be a better way to write it without runtime errors right? I thought of two alternatives, this:

```
type TmpSpreadsheet = TmpFile Spreadsheet
type TmpPicture     = TmpFile Picture
type TmpVideo       = TmpFile Video

videoPath :: TmpVideo -> FilePath
```

Or this:

```
data TmpFile a = TmpFile a FilePath
  deriving Show

videoPath :: TmpFile Video -> FilePath
```

But obviously they don't compile. What's the proper way to do it? Some other ideas, none particularly appealing:

- Wrap `TmpFile` in the format instead of the other way around, so the values are `Video (TmpFile "test.avi")` etc.
- Make lots of separate data types `VideoTmpFile`, `PictureTmpFile` etc.
- Make a `TmpFile` typeclass
- Use partial functions everywhere, but add guard functions to abstract the pattern matching

I also considered learning the `-XDataKinds` extension, but suspect I'm missing something much simpler that can be done without it.

EDIT: I'm learning a lot today! I tried both the approaches outlined below (`DataKinds` and phantom types, which have dummy value constructors that can be removed with another extension), and they both work! Then I tried to go a little further. They both let you make a nested type `TmpFile (ListOf a)` in addition to regular `TmpFile a`, which is cool. But I've tentatively decided to go with plain phantom types (intact value constructors), because you can pattern match on them. For example, I was surprised that this actually works:

```
data Spreadsheet = Spreadsheet deriving Show
data Picture     = Picture     deriving Show
data Video       = Video       deriving Show
data ListOf a    = ListOf a    deriving Show

data TmpFile a = TmpFile a FilePath
  deriving Show

videoPath :: TmpFile Video -> FilePath
videoPath (TmpFile Video p) = p

-- read a file that contains a list of filenames of type a,
-- and return them as individual typed tmpfiles
listFiles :: TmpFile (ListOf a) -> IO [TmpFile a]
listFiles (TmpFile (ListOf fmt) path) = do
  txt <- readFile path
  let paths = map (TmpFile fmt) (lines txt)
  return paths

vidPath :: TmpFile Video
vidPath = TmpFile Video "video1.txt"

-- $ cat videos.txt
-- video1.avi
-- video2.avi
vidsList :: TmpFile (ListOf Video)
vidsList = TmpFile (ListOf Video) "videos.txt"

main :: IO [FilePath]
main = do
  paths <- listFiles vidsList  -- [TmpFile Video "video1.avi",TmpFile Video "video2.avi"]
  return $ map videoPath paths -- ["video1.avi","video2.avi"]
```

As far as I can tell, the equivalent with `DataKinds` is very similar, but can't access `fmt` as a value:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

data FileFormat
  = Spreadsheet
  | Picture
  | Video
  | ListOf FileFormat
  deriving Show

data TmpFile (a :: FileFormat) = TmpFile FilePath
  deriving Show

vidPath :: TmpFile Video
vidPath = TmpFile "video.avi"

vidsList :: TmpFile (ListOf Video)
vidsList = TmpFile "videos.txt"

videoPath :: TmpFile Video -> FilePath
videoPath (TmpFile p) = p

listFiles :: TmpFile (ListOf a) -> IO [TmpFile a]
listFiles (TmpFile path) = do
  txt <- readFile path
  let paths = map TmpFile (lines txt)
  return paths

main :: IO [FilePath]
main = do
  paths <- listFiles vidsList
  return $ map videoPath paths
```

(It may seem like a weird thing to want, but my actual program is going to be an interpreter for a small language that compiles to Shake rules with a tmpfile corresponding to each variable, so typed lists of tmpfiles will be useful)

Does that seem right? I like the idea of `DataKinds` better, so I would go with it instead if I could inspect them as values, or if it turns out that's never needed.

Comment: it depends a bit on what you want to do - for example for what I've seen from your question I would indeed choose simple (separate) `newtype` wrappers like `newtype VideoPath = VideoPath FilePath`

Comment: or take the *phantom type* approach: `data TempFile a = TempFile FilePath` with `data Videoformat` (needs GHC extension `EmptyDataDecls`) and then `let videoFile = TempFile myPath :: TempFile Videoformat` ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right: with `-XDataKinds`, the `TmpFile Video -> FilePath` approach would work. And indeed I think this may be a good application for that extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data TmpFile (a :: FileFormat) = TmpFile FilePath
  deriving Show

videoPath :: TmpFile Video -> FilePath
```

The reason you need this extension to write `TmpFile Video` is that the constructors of `FileFormat` are ab initio *value-level* (thus only exist at runtime), while `TmpFile` is type-level / compile-time.

Of course there's another way to generate type-level entities: *define types*!

```
data Spreadsheet = Spreadsheet
data Picture = Picture
data Video = Video

data TmpFile a = TmpFile a FilePath
  deriving Show

videoPath :: TmpFile Video -> FilePath
```

Such types are called phantom types. But really, they're a bit of a hack to work around the former lack of proper type-level values, which DataKinds has now given us. So, unless you need compatibility with old compilers, do use DataKinds!

An alternative would be to *not* enforce the file type at compile time, but simply make it explicit that the functions are partial.

```
data TmpFile = TmpFile FileFormat FilePath
  deriving Show

videoPath :: TmpFile -> Maybe FilePath
videoPath (TmpFile Video p) = p
videoPath _ = Nothing
```

In fact, that approach might well be the more rational one, depending on what you're planning to do.

Comment: "Phantom type" usually refers to a type constructor that is parameterized by a type variable that it doesn't use.

Comment: @DerekElkins: I think it refers to the _parameters_ which aren't actually used in some type.

Comment: I agree, I would say "phantom type variables" not just "phantom types", but that isn't how people seem to use it. [Phantom type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type)

Comment: I guess I can remove my answer as it's basically yours minus the data-kind approach

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would advice against using such exotic extensions as "DataKinds" unless you absolutely need them. The reason is quite practical and general: the more language concepts you use to solve your problem, the harder it is to reason about your code.

Besides, "DataKinds" isn't an easy concept to wrap a head around. It is a transitional concept crossing two universes simultaneously: the values and the types. Personally I find it quite controversial and would only apply it when I have no other option.

In your case you've already found two ways of approaching your problem simpler, without "DataKinds":

> - Wrap TmpFile in the format instead of the other way around, so the values are Video (TmpFile "test.avi") etc.
> - Make lots of separate data types VideoTmpFile, PictureTmpFile etc.

I particularly like the idea of the wrapping types, because it is flexible and composable. Here's how I'd build up on it:

```
newtype Video a =
  Video a
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

newtype Picture a =
  Picture a
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

videoPath :: Video FilePath -> FilePath
```

You can notice two things:

1. `Video` and `Picture` are general concepts, which are not bound to just your temporary files, and they already implement some standard interfaces. This means that they can be reused for other purposes.
2. There is an obvious pattern in the definitions of `Video` and `Picture`.

---

The pattern that you see in `Video` and `Picture` can be called "refinement types" and is abstracted from in [the "refined" package](http://nikita-volkov.github.io/refined/) among others. So you might be interested in that.

---

As for your other options:

> - Make a TmpFile typeclass
> - Use partial functions everywhere, but add guard functions to abstract the pattern matching

That's a definite "No" to both. Don't breed typeclasses, leave them be for the truely general concepts, which have laws and likely a (Category) theory behind them. The language provides you plentiful other ways to abstract. Also don't let partial functions crawl out to your APIs - there's a consensus in the community that it's an antipattern.

Comment: Good point, I think I'll avoid using DataKinds because it's one more language concept to remember, and I do find it confusing (added tickmarks, and the kinds are omitted when pattern matching even though they show up in the function type signatures). I haven't been able to get the pattern matching working with refinement types either though, because you can't get the actual value without specifying the format first. For example I would try to match on `listFiles (ListOf (fmt (TmpFile p)))`, which doesn't work without knowing `fmt`.